# Problem with QUERY and IMPORTRANGE | Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Why this function does not display results for one of the ranges? With no QUERY the results are displayed correctly.

```
QUERY({
IMPORTRANGE("url";"Sheet1!A1:B5");
IMPORTRANGE("url";"Sheet2!A1:B5");
IMPORTRANGE("url";"Sheet3!A1:B5")};
"SELECT Col1, WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL")
```

Comment: I removed the jQuery tag because it's not a jQuery question

Comment: *"Why this function does not display results for one of the ranges?"* There may be [mixed data](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) on the specific range. In any case please share a test sheet so you can be easier helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT({
 IMPORTRANGE("url"; "Sheet1!A1:B5");
 IMPORTRANGE("url"; "Sheet2!A1:B5");
 IMPORTRANGE("url"; "Sheet3!A1:B5")});
 "select Col1 where Col1 is not null"; 0))
```